# Not able to compile Java programs even after changing the PATH variable?

Tags: java, path

I have recently installed Windows 8 Pro in my Laptop.

I have downloaded the latest Java 7 Update 11 from [java.com](http://java.com) and installed in the system.

I have changed the `$PATH` variable and it's current value is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

But still I am geting:

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have even restarted my computer once.

What's wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

`javac` is in the development kit (JDK), not the runtime environment (JRE).

I can't remember the exact windows path, but look for a `jdk` folder and then find the `bin` folder underneath that.

Edit:  You did install the Java development kit version, didn't you?  [Download here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) if you didn't.

The link at [java.com](http://java.com) is for the `jre`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download Java JDK, and add to environment variable PATH your path to bin directory in your SDK.

After it open `cmd` and type

```
java -version
```

you can check it with this command.